# How to find the number of ways the $24$ unshaded squares in the grid can be tiled

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

[image]

Firstly, we see that some tiles can combine to $2 \times 3$ tiles lying around shaded square. and there are $2$ ways arranging $2 \times 3$ tiles around shaded square.

In each case :

- in one $2 \times 3$ tile: there are $3$ ways arranging three $1 \times 2$ tiles so that we have $3^4=81$ for each way
  but some way to tile $5 \times 5$ grid can be counted in both cases. In that way , $2 \times 2$ tile in $4$ corners is tiled by two $1 \times  2$ tiles. Hence, there are $2^4=16$ ways.
  In conclusion , answer is $81 \times 2 - 16 = 146$
  Am I wrong?

Comment: Or an inner circle of 4 with an outer circle of 8

Comment: What kind of class is this from?  I would think you are expected to write a backtracking program to compute this.  Your answer is certainly not convincing in the way it is explained.

Comment: What about this tiling? It can't be broken into four 2x3s. https://i.imgur.com/vd00ZqN.jpeg

Comment: Class Hight  school

Comment: You could also use two horizontal dominoes, one in the top left and one in the top right corner, and then fill the rest with vertical dominoes. This does not split into four 2x3 areas, nor does it match Empy2's inner and outer square pattern.

Comment: Personally I would first look at the four dominoes that are adjacent to the centre., and what arrangements they can have. Up to rotations/reflections, I think there are 9 cases. For each of those you can count how many ways there are to complete the tiling, and how many rotations/reflections this has, and then add them up.

Comment: This problem is in purple comet math meet 2016 year .